# Html2Pdf and the attribute style [tinymce's fault]

Tags: php, html2pdf

i'm trying to convert some text from a tinymce editor,
but html2pdf does not seem to read the css style.

Example:

```
<p>On the left</p>
<p style="text-align: right;">On the right</p>
<p style="text-align: center;">It the center</p>
```

The code above produces only text aligned on the left.
Html tags like  or  work.

Maybe it's a problem with the installation?
Am I missing something?
ps.: sorry for my bad english...

**UPDATE:** found the problem, tinymce's text passed trought method post, is converted from:

```
<p style="text-align: right;">right</p>
```

to:

```
<p style="\&quot;text-align:" right;\"="">right</p>
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't really have an answer, but I just tested this in mPDF and it worked as you would expect. Maybe html2pdf is treating paragraph tags as inline elements? Have you tried `<p style="text-align: right; width:500px;">On the right</p>` or something similar?

Comment: "text-align: right; width:500px;", "text-align: right; width:100%;", same result: the text is always on the left :(